# insert associative array into mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got an associative array that looks like

```
$rates = array (
    'AUD' => '0.5',
    'BRL' => '1.2',
    'CAD' => '0.6',
    'CHF' => '0.4',
    'CZK' => '1.5',
 );
```

I want to put this array in mysql so that i can use the rates to make an currency converter.
mine question is how do you do that i tried

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "eurotoforgein";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$table = 'rates';

$keys = implode(', ', array_keys($rates));
$values = "'" . implode("','", array_values($rates)) . "'";

$sql = 'insert into '.$table.'('.$keys.') values ('.$values.')';


if(!$result = $conn->query($sql)){ 

die('There was an error running the query [' . $conn->error . ']'); 

}

else{
echo "Data inserted.";
}
```

the error i got is 
There was an error running the query [Unknown column 'AUD' in 'field list']
for the table used

```
// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE eurotoforgein (
COUNTRY VARCHAR(6),
RATES FLOAT(10)

)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
```

any help is welcome 
thanks

Comment: I'll give you a hint. `INSERT INTO eurotoforgein (COUNTRY, RATES) VALUES ('AUD', 0.5)`, not `INSERT INTO eurotoforgein (AUD) VALUES (0.5)`

Comment: SQL requires string literals to be quoted (same as almost every single programming language that exists).... better yet, enter the 21st centurey and use prepared statements with bind variables using MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Note also that money is frequently DECIMAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can generate an insert for multiple values like this

```
$pairs = [];
foreach($rates as $key => $value)
{
    $pairs[] = "('$key', $value)";
}
$pairs_str = implode(',', $pairs);

$sql = 'insert into '.$table.' (COUNTRY, RATES) values ' . $pairs_str;
```